# Postgresql Update Query Hangs - but will complete if I add 1 minute pause

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, locking

I have an ETL job that consists of 18 steps.  It inserts records into several tables.  Then near the end of the job there are a few queries that add additional data using an update.  No tables/index altering is done.

If I run the queries in sequence, the job will 'hang' on the first update query.  It spins forever and never finishes.  If I put a 60 second pause before the update, then the update completes in less than 10 seconds.

While the update is 'stuck' i run

```
select pid, state, usename, query, query_start, NOW() - query_start AS duration
from pg_stat_activity 
where pid in (
  select pid from pg_locks l 
  join pg_class t on l.relation = t.oid 
  and t.relkind = 'r' 
);
```

and i see the update query.

Note that this postgre server is only doing this one thing.  There are no other users.

There must be something happening that I'm not seeing with the inserts. How can I know when the inserts are complete so my update doesn't hang?  Why doesn't the update automatically continue after whatever is locking it completes?

Here is the update:

```
    UPDATE warehouse.public.inv_sum_br_matl_by_month w
        SET "Frozen YYYYMM" = m."Frozen YYYYMM"
    FROM (
        WITH frozen AS (
            WITH materials AS (
                SELECT r."Branch", r."SAP No"
                FROM warehouse.public.inv_sum r 
                WHERE 
                    r."Spcl Stk" IN ('', 'W')
                    AND r."YYYYMM" = '200908'
                GROUP BY r."Branch", r."SAP No"
            )
            SELECT 
                m."Branch"
                , m."SAP No"
                , ms."X Matl Stat"
                , bms."Br Matl Stat"
            FROM materials m
            LEFT JOIN warehouse.public.inv_sum_matl_by_month ms 
                ON 
                    ms."SAP No" = m."SAP No" 
                    AND ms."YYYYMM" = '200908'
            LEFT JOIN warehouse.public.inv_sum_br_matl_by_month bms 
                ON 
                    bms."Branch" = m."Branch" 
                    AND bms."SAP No" = m."SAP No" 
                    AND bms."YYYYMM" = '200908' 
        )
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (f."Branch", f."SAP No", l."YYYYMM")
            f."Branch"
            , f."SAP No"
            , CASE 
                WHEN f."X Matl Stat" = 'OB' THEN ''
                WHEN f."X Matl Stat" NOT IN ('FR','ZF','ZM') AND f."Br Matl Stat" NOT IN ('FR','ZF','ZM') THEN ''
                ELSE COALESCE(l."YYYYMM",'200908')
                END AS "Frozen YYYYMM"
        FROM frozen f
        LEFT JOIN warehouse.public.inv_sum_br_matl_by_month l
            ON 
                l."Branch" = f."Branch" 
                AND l."SAP No" = f."SAP No" 
                AND l."YYYYMM" < '200908'
        ORDER BY f."Branch", f."SAP No", l."YYYYMM" DESC
    ) AS m
    WHERE 
            w."Branch"   = m."Branch"
        AND w."SAP No"   = m."SAP No"
        AND w."YYYYMM"   = '200908'
    RETURNING 1
)
SELECT count(*) AS "RecCnt" FROM rows;
```

Comment: The pause likely give autovac and auto analyze to kick in and do their thing.  Without them, it may choose an extremely poor execution plan, given that it is making the plan based on old data.  You can manually VACUUM ANALYZE, or just ANALYZE, the tables which changed a lot, before starting the update.

Comment: Thank you jjanes!  Adding a vacuum analyze <table> after each step fixed the 'hang' problem.  I've been using postgresql for several years now with all our ETL and this is the first time i've had this problem.  Still curious why the update would hang indefinitely though?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the EXPLAIN.  Probably the plan was so awful that it just never finished.

Comment: I was strugling with the same issue, after adding the VACUUM ANALYSE to some steps of my process, the queries started running with no problems. @jjanes